# Copy and paste values without duplicates in spredsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, copy-paste

I wanna copy and paste only the values (not formula) from source range to target without the duplicates (some values that are alredy in target range). I tried following a couple of tutorials online to start with the copy-paste part (not even the unique conditional) but keep on getting the error "the parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange ... ". Don't really know why, since I'm using the same code. Also tried something with copyTo instead of setValues but get the same error.

```
function paste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = spreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var sourceValues = source.getValues();

  var rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  var columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

  var target = spreadsheet.getRange(1,4, rowCount, columnCount);
  target.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Here's a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cAoG3ms4e384nWCZe2wBNQUkExnIQ1zZertYXlwQT0I/edit?usp=sharing) of what I'd like to get.
I know it would be easier with formula, but the thing is my data in Source is dynamic because it's coming from an ImportXML so sometimes the extracted data just disappears, which is why I wanna paste just values when I get them before they goes missing.

Comment: Only show the error with the code you're showing in your question. See [mcve]

Comment: This type of problem is normally easily resolved by stepping through the script with the debugger and looking at the results of every intermediate step.  In some cases you may have to create intermediate variables to see the data in the debugger.  Once you've learned how to use the debugger you will find the need for such questions diminishes greatly.  Learning how to code requires learning how to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
function appendA2bToD2e() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A2:B');
  const target = ss.getRange('Sheet1!D2:E');
  appendUniquesToRange_(source, target);
}

function appendUniquesToRange_(sourceRange, targetRange) {
  const dataToAppend = sourceRange.getValues();
  const existingData = targetRange.getValues();
  const newData = existingData
    .concat(dataToAppend)
    .filter((row, rowIndex, array) =>
      array
        .map(tuple => tuple[0])
        .indexOf(row[0]) === rowIndex && row[0] !== ''
    );
  targetRange
    .clearContent()
    .offset(0, 0, newData.length, newData[0].length)
    .setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: thank you, works like a charm! I'll look into the methods you've used

Comment: one more question. And if I want to get in source a range that is different collums for ex. (A,C,D) (but skip over B). How would I do it? tried something I read in another question with RangeList, and then using splice, but can't really make them work. Thanks

Comment: Use `const dataToAppend = sourceRange.getValues().map(row => [row[0], row[2], row[3]]);` or similar. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).