# Append rows of unique data in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I got and tweaked the following code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412554/copy-and-paste-values-without-duplicates-in-spredsheets). I want a function that pastes only unique data from a live sync Salesforce report in another sheet. However, it's currently only using my 0 value to identify unique data; I just want to alter it to consider the entire row of data.

Example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17A0Avxayn-6VGJnwy5IdyePQoZN_jQ8yvkeH7MMz67k/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function appending() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = ss.getRange('Sync!A3:K');
  const target = ss.getRange('Report!H3:R');
  appendUniquesToRange_(source, target);
}

function appendUniquesToRange_(sourceRange, targetRange) {
  const dataToAppend = sourceRange.getValues();
  const existingData = targetRange.getValues();
  const newData = existingData
    .concat(dataToAppend)
    .filter((row, rowIndex, array) =>
      array
        .map(tuple => tuple[0])
        .indexOf(row[0]) === rowIndex && row[0] !== ''
    );
  targetRange
    .clearContent()
    .offset(0, 0, newData.length, newData[0].length)
    .setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a spreadsheet with a data sample and include your expected outcome?

I ask you this, because when you say "I just want to alter it to consider the entire row of data." it's not clear if you want to validate all cells values to prevent duplicates or if you'll be allowing a certain amount of data duplicated.

Comment: @MilagroSosa just provided a spreadsheet in the original post. Expected outcome is that any unique identifier anywhere on the row will constitute that row being appended into the Report sheet. For example, rows 3 and 4 on the Sync sheet are virtually identical except for their product name, rows 3 and 6 are identical except for geo targeting.

Comment: @cwoolf27 could you please elaborate more on this: `it's currently only using my 0 value to identify unique data; I just want to alter it to consider the entire row of data.` ? I just tested using your sample sheet and if I add a row with a different `Account Name` the entire row gets copied over to the `Report` sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a different way to address your particular request.

The code you used was created specifically to compare one particular value as the `identifier`. However, you can achieve what you need with a simpler code:

```
function appending() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = ss.getRange('Sync!A3:K');
  const target = ss.getRange('Report!H3:R');  
  const dataToAppend = source.getValues();
  target.clearContent().setValues(dataToAppend)            
}

function removerDuplicate() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange("Report!H3:R" + sheet.getLastRow()).removeDuplicates();
}
```

You can give it a shot with this piece of code and see how it works with your sheet, if you happen to have any questions or comments, let me know.

Comment: I get this error:
`10:41:43 PM
Error
Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 999 but the range has 70.
appending`

Also, I like the format of the first one because I'll be appending only new data from a live sync, I don't want my report to keep running back through and checking old data once it has a unique row, just making sure it doesn't add any new identical rows.